# In batch files calls to executables are sequential or not?

Tags: batch-file

Let say ,I have a batch file and I have three commands like:

Execute A process --- Step 1
Execute B process --- Step 2
Execute C process --- Step 3

So,if my step 1 takes time to execute then will the control wait for its completion and then go to Step 2 or all the steps may gets executed in parallel?

Comment: They are system commands like :xcopy,md,etc

Comment: As the existing answers say - the commands will run sequentially. If you need to run commands in parallel then you can run them via the START command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are commands (internal commands like DOS commands or XP's commands), they will wait (run sequentially).

If they are external processes/programs, they won't unless you start them with `start /wait [program]`.

Answer (score 0):

They will execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

They will **NOT** be executed in parallel, they are sequentially executed. It's the same with any Unix/Linux Script. In fact most "Shell scripts" are executed this way.